# Nearly identical methods in PagesController produce an undefined method error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables in my Rails 4 app -- one for *Game*, *Category*, and *Topic*. Both *Category* and *Topic* have a column for `:name`, while *Game* includes information like `starts_at` for when a game begins.

In my *PagesController*, I can show data from both *Game* and *Topic* by using `find_by` with the params value:

```
 topic = Topic.find_by_name(params[:topic])
 @games = Game.for_topic(topic).upcoming.order(:starts_at)
```

This works fine.

What's weird is that when I use the same reasoning but with *Category* instead of *Topic*, like so:

```
 category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
 @games = Game.for_category(category).upcoming.order(:starts_at)
```

I receive an error message:

```
undefined method `for_category'
```

This is confusing to me since I am definitely defining category and the using it in my for_ expression. Am I making an error in my thinking?

**Additional**

*CreateCategories Migration*

```
 class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
    t.belongs_to :topic, index: true
     t.string :name, :null => false

     t.timestamps
    end
   end
  end
```

*CreateTopics Migration*

```
 class CreateTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :topics do |t|
       t.string :name, :null => false

       t.timestamps
      end
     end
   end
```

Comment: What is the "`for_` expression" you are talking about? Is that some kind `method_missing`-defined method for scopes? Can you post its definition?

Comment: How does your `Game` model source look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you setup the named scope `for_topic` in the `Game` model. But is missing the `for_category`, which is why it is failing.

Try setting the named scope `for_category` in `Game` model.